# How to scale count of unread messages in ActiveRecord scout app shows possible n+1 on the count(*) unread messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord

How to remove n+1 on count of unread messages, scout app show possible n+1 on the count query in active record rails ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for `.includes`? Say, `User` `has_many :articles` (and `Article` `belongs_to :user`), so you can `Article.all.includes(:user)` which would make one query for all users, instead of making a separate query for each individual user.

Docs: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."task_id" = ? AND (has_been_read = ? and user_id != ? )  this query is causing n+1

Comment: @user9361511 well how exactly do you get that query? What line of code generates it?

Comment: if tasks.present?
      tasks.each do |as|
         if as.status !="Closed"
           if as.comment.present?
             c_count = as.comment.where(:has_been_read => false).count
             comment_count += c_count > 0 ? c_count : 0
           end
         end
      end
   end